# Tensorflow - training Adam

Tags: tensorflow, matrix, optimization

I try to build my first simple neural network with tensorflow, above you can see my code. My code can calculate the loss, but when i try to add the train_step i got the error message `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [2,2], In[1]: [1024,1]`, which says that the dimensions of the matrxis aren't compatible, but i don't understand the dimensions. In my opinion they must be [1] and [1]...

```
input=[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
labels=[1,1]

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 5])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

hidden = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
output = tf.layers.dense(inputs=hidden, units=1)

loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(y, output)
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1).minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(init)
     for i in range(1):
         result = sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: input,y: labels})
         print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is due to your input and labels being inconsistent.  For your inputs, you have 2 input vectors with dimensions (1, 5).  In your output layer, you have one output.  And in your labels, you have only one example of dimension (1,2).

Two fixes depending on what you wanted to do.  If you meant to do two training examples (which is what it looks like you're doing):

```
input=[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
labels=[[1],[1]]
```

and keep the rest the same.  This way, you have 2 input vectors, and 2 label examples.

Second possible interpretation, where you are feeding in 2 input vectors, both with the label of [1, 1].  Then keep everything the same, but change the output layer to:

```
output = tf.layers.dense(inputs=hidden, units=2)
```

I'm pretty sure the first fix is what you're looking for.  Also your code will never update your neural network because you did not sess.run(train_step) anywhere.  If you want it to actually train, you'll need that step as well.